# Enforcing Read-Write Splitting in .NET 8 Web API with Azure SQL Geo-Replication

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, .net-8.0

I am currently working on a .NET 8 Web API project that interacts with an Azure SQL database configured with active geo-replication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview?view=azuresql). To optimize performance, I want to enforce a read-write splitting strategy where read operations are directed to the geo-secondary database, and write operations are sent to the primary database.

To achieve this, I plan to use the ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly parameter in the connection string for read operations. However, I'm unsure about the implementation details and how to correctly connect to the readable secondary database.

Could someone provide a code sample or guidance on how to modify the connection string and connect to the geo-secondary database for read operations while ensuring that write operations are directed to the primary database?

Based on my analysis, I came across the below link :

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-172-applicationintent-readonly-in-general-purpose/ba-p/2375941

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation

Comment: It look like all you are doing is changing the Server in the connection string to access either the Primary or Secondary Database.  You wand the two databases (primary, secondary) to share data so need to link the databases.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks @jdweng for your response. I want to know what should be there in the connectionstring which connects to the secondary logical server. Initially  I thought ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly will solve the issue but based on the article :https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-172-applicationintent-readonly-in-general-purpose/ba-p/2375941  it does not seem to work. Any help on this request is much appreciated

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-only-routing-for-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Can anyone help me to know are there any drawbacks for setting up active geo-replication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview?view=azuresql). In case there are any better approaches please suggest me in this case

Comment: See Next Step which has sample code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview?view=azuresql#next-steps